# Can I combine mypy reports with pytest coverage reports?

Tags: pytest, code-coverage, mypy, test-coverage

I can generate a type "coverage" report with [mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/) via

```
mypy . --html-report mypy-report
```

and a pytest coverage report with [pytest-cov](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov/)

```
pytest --cov=app --cov-report=html
```

Is there a way to combine both reports? I would be interested in code that is neither covered by unit tests nor by mypy.

Comment: Don't know of an existing solution, but are you locked into HTML? Using line coverage from `mypy` (`--lineprecision-report`) and `pytest` would make parsing the common coverage much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a little time on this, and made *some* progress, but don't have a fully working solution.

Both `pytest` and `mypy` have flags to emit an XML-based report, and the one common schema they share is for the Java-based [Cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) tool.

Example invocation to produce an XML file for each:

```
pytest --cov=app --cov-report=xml:pytest-cobertura.xml
mypy app.py --cobertura-xml-report .
```

After this, you'll have two similar XML files named:

- `pytest-cobertura.xml`
- `coverage.xml` - `mypy` will only allow a directory, not a filename

I've explored trying to merge these two files into a single one, but haven't been able to successfully do so in the time I've spent on this - but it should be something along the lines of parsing the XML tree and merging the two sets of `lines` XML tags and creating a `combined.xml` file.

Right now, each file individually can be rendered to either terminal or HTML with the [`pycobertura`](https://pypi.org/project/pycobertura/) tool, like so:

```
pycobertura show --format html --output coverage.html combined.xml
```

I haven't been able to figure out the merging just yet, but wanted to give you what I had figured out.